# org-mode inline html while exporting using ox-pandoc

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html, pandoc

I am not able to use inline html through macro in org-mode when exporting through ox-pandoc. For example if I use `@@html:<span class="small">@@Small Text@@html:</span>@@` and export the document to HTML5 through ox-pandoc, it just removes the html and gives out normal text. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This happens as ox-pandoc tries to work around some of pandoc's missing org-mode features by first exporting via the org-mode `org` exporter and calling pandoc on the result. The `org` exporter discards all non-org snippets. I'm not aware of any way to prevent this; calling pandoc directly is probably the only option.